# robotframework ValueError: Argument 'arg' got value 'x.y' (x) that cannot be converted to x

Tags: python, enums, robotframework

I have updated my robotframework to v4.1.0.
Now, I get error for on Enums.
I have an python code which contain an Enum like below:

```
@enum.unique
class x(enum.Enum):
y= 0x00
z= 0x01
```

and I have an arg in my robot testcase defined as below:

```
arg = x.y
```

And I get below error when I run robot testcase
ValueError: Argument 'arg' got value 'x.y' (x) that cannot be converted to x

Could you please let me why the error occurred and what is the solution?

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible case, so we can test on our own.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I updated Robot framework from `v4.0` to `v4.1`. I have fixed it by using `enum.IntEnum` instead of `enum.Enum`. So, please try to update your example as follows:

```
@enum.unique
class X(enum.IntEnum):
    y = 0x00
    z = 0x01
```

Hope that fixes your issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).